# Who is the drow woman depicted on the cover of Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage?

Tags: dnd-5e, art, waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage

Who is the drow woman depicted on the [cover](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/File:WaterdeepDungeonOfTheMadMageCover.png) of *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*? Is it Vlonwelv Auvryndar, Erelal Freth, or someone else?

Comment: @Jason_c_o: Indeed, there's a very strong possibility that the answer is something like "the three characters in the middle-ground are just generic high-level antagonist monsters", but not owning the book, I can't say that with any confidence. I know it's against our policy to give partial answers in the comments, but when I don't have critical knowledge in situations like this, I'm a bit stumped on what to do.

Comment: @Blckknght a good thing to do (IMO) in a case like this is to leave that comment under an answer, to say "this might be some additional support for what you wrote...." I know in this case you came by before there were any answers, though. I've deleted the comment and copied it into the existing answer so that author can use it if they like; otherwise you can see the text in the answer's revision history if you'd like to grab it to post as an answer-comment.

Answer (score 1):

The book in question has only this to say (on page 2, On the Cover):

> Cynthia Sheppard illustrates a host of villains vying for control of
> the dungeon's depths.

According to [Dragon+](https://dnd.dragonmag.com/2020/04/30/waterdeeps-movie-moments/content.html), the artist herself has said:

> The drow female is the closest to the real me. That’s my ‘judgment
> face’, with different hair and pointy ears.

(hat tip to Blckknght)

Not sure how accurate it is, but [Partial Arc](https://www.partialarc.com/articles//how-we-roll-154-what-we-know-about-waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage-stream-of-many-eyes-recap-part-2) refers to the character merely as "a drow queen". While I don't know if there is a drow queen in the adventure, [fandom](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Vlonwelv_Auvryndar) does refer to Vlonwelv as a princess.